# How to run Magento 2 from a subdirectory

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento2

I'm trying to set up a Magento 2 site that will run with http://www.example.com/store/ as its home page, but Magento's router is treating that subdirectory path as a frontend module name, and trying to run a module called `store` that doesn't exist.

My base URLs are configured as such:

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%url';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                         |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
|         2 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | http://www.example.com/store/ |
|         3 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url   | http://www.example.com/store/ |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+---------- --------------------+
```

With this setup, I updated the Nginx config, altering the `location` declarations to include `/store` at the beginning. Once that was done I was able to access the site and static assets were loading properly, however any page I tried to access resulted in Magento's fancy 404 page.

Since I knew the request was making it into the Mageto app, I had a hunch that Magento's routing was causing the issue. To test, I created a new module with a simple controller at `/app/code/MyModules/Store/Controllers/Index/Index.php`, and gave it a router with a frontName of `store`. Once I activated that module and reloaded the page, instead of a 404 I got the simple JSON output I had set up in my custom controller. So I *know* that Magento is getting the request and thinks the initial subdirectory that is part of its base URL is actually a frontName route.

So at this point I have two questions:

1. Is it even possible to run a Magento 2 store in a subdirectory like this, or do I have to resort to using a subdomain?
2. Assuming the answer to 1 is "yes, it is possible", what am I missing to make this work? I feel like there must be some setting somewhere that will resolve this, but I simply don't know where to look anymore.

Comment: Just a heads up my answer has not been tested with a NGINX server but from my Magento experience it should still be valid.

Comment: I wrote a post about this https://jokiruiz.com/magento-2/how-to-run-magento-2-from-a-subdirectory/ I hopep it helps. It is just create the folder inside the /pub/ folder as everything goes through there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking this on the [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) and see if you can get more help if the following doesn't work.

**My Experience**
The short answer to your question is yes. Magento 2 works fine with subdirectories. I actually just pulled our website off a sub directory /store and went back to not having one. Well adding a sub directory and removing one are two different things I still ran into issues similar to what you are having. Here is what I did to debug/ fix the issue:

1. From the dashboard check your configuration settings to see if it really is pulling in the correct web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url, this is under Stores > Configuration > Web. It sounds like it is but if not debug and fix this first.
2. Through your hosting terminal or over SSH completely delete (remove) the var/di directory and var/view_processed directory.
3. Again through your hosting terminal or over SSH run the following commands which assume you are at the root directory of your Magento installation. You may or may not need the php part and I did add extra commands because I don't know what you have done so far. None of these should harm anything.

> php bin/magento cache:flush
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

You may need to follow this by manually running the Full Page Cache in the admin dashboard under System > Cache management. After that make sure you hit F5 when you first check the front-end of your website so your browser refreshes its own cache of the site and everything should be working now.

**The Main Problem**
Magento 2 has done some amazing things to improve the user experience and speed up page load times. One of these things is improvements in caching which as you can see can cause a lot of problems for developers. When in doubt just refresh everything with the commands I posted and it usually resolves a lot of issues.

**Update**
Sorry just realized you did ask on the [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/). One thing I should mention is I **did not** just copy the index.php and .htaccess file over to the /store directory. I actually moved the whole Magento installation into the /store directory before doing any of the stuff I mentioned. Then when I didn't need /store anymore I moved everything out and followed the steps I mentioned.